# Manage Flash player with multimedia keys

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, flash

I listen to music online. Streaming services usually provide a Flash player to manage the stream (pause, go to next track, alter volume, etc.). This player can’t be managed from multimedia keyboard like desktop music players.

Is there a Firefox plugin which listens for multimedia keys and commands online music players accordingly?

Use case:
Start YouTube music, minimize Firefox, continue daily work. Pause music to make the call, skip bad track without opening Firefox and interrupting your work.